# Sorting in python does not work

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

i'm a beginning python programmer and i'm trying to write a code that sorts data in an array in increasing order as below:

```
A = [2,3,6,8,4,5,7,123,543,65435,31,43]
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    if A[i] > A[i+1]:
        A[i] , A[i+1] = A[i+1] , A[i]
print (A)
```

However the result returns this:

```
[2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 123, 543, 31, 43, 65435]
```

May I know what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could try : `sorted(A)`

Comment: You're only comparing each element in `A` with the next element. Sorting is more complex than that. Go read about sorting algorithms.

Comment: Your solution will only push the highest element to the rear. Take a look at Bubble sort

Comment: (Preferably *not* bubble sort. [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is good for small lists.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only performing a single stage of bubble-sort; to get the list completely sorted, you would have to float the numbers up `n - 1` times, not only one.

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        if A[i] > A[i+1]:
            A[i] , A[i+1] = A[i+1] , A[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do Bubble Sort. Actually the part of your code works, In your result the greatest element is at the end of the sorted array. Now you have to do the same for all remaining elements in a nested for loop. That's why Bubble Sort has the complexity of O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [2,3,6,8,4,5,7,123,543,65435,31,43]
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    for j in range(i+1):
        if A[i] > A[j]:
            A[i] , A[j] = A[j] , A[i]
print A
```

Sorting needs comparing an element with rest of the elements in that array